# Find text boxes whose value is 'something' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to find the DOM elements who are text boxes and whose value is 'xyz' with attribute selector that too without using each() function.

```
  <input type='text' id='txtAl' value='xyz' />
  <br /><br />
  <input type='text' id='txtBl' value='xyz' />
  <br /><br />
  <input type='text' id='txtCl' value='xyz' />
  <br /><br />
  <input type='text' id='txtCl' value='ABC' />
  <br/><br />
  <input type='text' id='txtCl' value='DEF' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use filter function:

```
var a = $('input[type="text"]').filter(function() { return $(this).val()=="xyz" });
```

check the working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jeh9ts46/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to test against current value.

```
var inputs = $('input:text').filter(function(){
     return this.value == SOMETHING;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('input[value="xyz"]')` to get all the selectors with value 'xyz'.

```
var arr = $('input[value="xyz"]'); //Get all the selectors
for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++) { // use for loop to loop all selectors
   var type = arr[i].type;
   if (type == 'text') {
       console.log(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a6cLq1w/)

Comment: But...doesn't this select on the original attribute values in the source HTML, and not the current values? Also, it doesn't limit to `type="text"`.

Comment: It also doesn't filter out "text" type inputs.

Comment: @JacobHeater  I have updated the code. Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that thing. :)

Comment: It's better to leverage selectors to do everything you're doing in your answer. At the minimum, you should be doing `$('input:text')`. Don't use `[value="xyz"]` to filter out element values. It doesn't look at the current element value. A better answer would be `$('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value === 'xyz'; });` Using jQuery's `filter` function is far more readable than a loop.